# Is there a performance cost for querying statistics of a column within a snowflake database?

Tags: statistics, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am planning on running some general statistics against the columns of a snowflake database.  Here are some sample abstracted queries.

select count(%column%) from %table%

select count(distinct %column%) from %table%

select min(%column%) from %table%

select max(%column%) from %table%

select avg(%column%) from %table%

select stddev(%column%) from %table%

Is there a performance cost to these queries or are the statistics already computed?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a cost to these queries or are the statistics already
> computed?

There is potentially a cost to all queries. All queries use Cloud Services credits. If CS usage remains below 10% of compute on the warehouses, it is not chargeable. If it is already over 10% because of current usage, then the CS for all these queries would be chargeable. Cloud Services is generally not a major contributor to costs.

With that out of the way we can discuss which of these are metadata queries and which ones will resume a suspended warehouse:

```
select count(%column%) from %table%           -- Metadata query

select count(distinct %column%) from %table%  -- Needs a warehouse 

select min(%column%) from %table%             -- Depends on data type

select max(%column%) from %table%             -- Depends on data type

select avg(%column%) from %table%             -- Needs a warehouse

select stddev(%column%) from %table%          -- Needs a warehouse
```

For the ones that depend on data type, in general you won't need a running warehouse to get a min/max (without a filter on the table) for fixed-precision numbers, dates and timestamps. Floating point numbers, varchar/string, arrays, variants, etc. will all require a running warehouse.